# Using IT in domain name good practice?

Tags: domains, keywords, domain-registration

i need to register domain for computer repair shop, say i found hypothetically **example.com** but its taken, so i tried **exampleIT.com** and its available, however its sounds kind of trivial with IT at the end even worse in my opinion than **ex4Pample.com** or something equally lame.

Are there any disadvantages of using IT in domain name?

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what the actual domain name and the name of the brand you're trying to create/represent is, I'd say sticking "IT" at the end is only meaningful if "IT" is part of your brand identity.

For most services "IT" is too vague to be meaningful and too generic to act as a qualifier. You're probably better off looking for a different TLD, a more relevant term or a more unique name altogether.

A lot of well-known web brands started out with domain names that weren't just "*brand*.com" because those were already taken (as most good dot-com domains are). For software you'd often find a prefix like "get" or a suffix like "now", "app", etc. You could even go with something as cheesy as "hq" (like *basecamphq.com*, which only recently moved to *basecamp.com*). Another one I've seen with companies is "weare" as a prefix, especially when the company name is very short.

Using a "spoof" domain (i.e. something that looks like the real thing but uses number/Unicode substitutions to swap out some characters with look-alikes like the "a"/4 substitution you suggested) is probably the worst option unless you're trying to look like a phishing attempt.

Answer (score 2):

you could check if the domain name is available with tld .IT. You can check availability: https://www.eurodns.com/international-domain-names/it-domain-registration/

TLD .it is for italian domain names but could fit very nice your bussines.

I my self have a romanian website with .it TLD in the IT bussines.

You could give it a look. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Pluma makes some good points. I just want to add a few more.

Adding IT to the domain name will not necessarily help with search performance. It will not sink into the SERPs as a search term, partly because `it` is a word, and `IT` is overly used. The keyword waters surrounding IT is murky at best.

Having said that, the domain name should be memorable and simple. It should become a `top of mind` (marketing speak) domain name even if they only hear/read it once (hopefully).

I think that adding `it` at the end will actually confuse the readers of the domain name. For example sillywillyit.com, billybobsit.com, chigacoit.com, etc. Okay some of these are silly and just for fun, but as you read these domain names, adding the `it` at the end makes it harder to read and absorb. I thought of a few that I had to refrain from typing. It is amazing how adding `it` to the end of a domain name can really skew the intent.

Selecting another TLD other than .com, .net, and .org can limit your reach in search engines considering that TLDs have a reach based upon performance. All TLDs experience this, however, the three main and original TLDs experience greater impressions and presence in search. If you are selling in the U.S. for example, selecting a .uk ccTLD will severely limit who sees your site even if you are a UK company.

I suggest thinking on possible domain names a bit harder and longer. I am sure you will find one you like better that will fit the bill just fine. It will come to you at an odd time so carry a pen and some paper with you! But for the smallest room in the house, you may only need the pen. [insert laugh track here or crickets] It seems that is the way. That is where I do my best thinking!

Answer (score 1):

I had a company name that had "IT" at the end of it. The reason why I changed it (to a completely different name) is because without the context of "Information Technology" people (especially people not in the industry) would call it "it" and not I.T. So your example would be "example it" and not "example eye tee". "Example it" sounds kinda dumb (believe me, I know) so I would avoid it altogether. In print you can use periods or make the letters capital to help, but in a web browser, you really can do that (at least not subdomains that close together [I.T.]). Take it from my experience. Find another domain name...